# Multi output target data is not supported with label binarization : OneVsRest Classifier

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm trying to perform a multiclass classification.
Here is my portion of the code:

```
    nb_classif = OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB()).fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)
    C = 1.0 #SVregularization parameter
    svc = OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=C)).fit(X_train_dtm,                         y_train)
    lin_svc = OneVsRestClassifier(svm.LinearSVC(C=C)).fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)
    sgd = OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier()).fit(X_train_dtm,y_train)
```

I'm getting the error

> Multi output target data is not supported with label binarization: OneVsRest Classifier

I printed my `X_train_dtm` and the output is

```
(0, 184)      1
(0, 2674)     1
(0, 2399)     1
(0, 536)      1
(0, 2673)     1
(0, 1977)     1
(0, 2252)     1
(0, 2577)     1
(0, 1538)     1
(0, 1027)     1
(0, 2582)     1
(0, 750)      1
(0, 2663)     1
(0, 2544)     1
(0, 2159)     1
(0, 2150)     1
(0, 1309)     1
(0, 1737)     1
(0, 543)      1
(0, 340)      1
(0, 2229)     1
(0, 1321)     1
(0, 38)       1
(0, 2475)     1
(0, 1738)     1
:     :
(349, 1097)   1
(349, 2949)   2
(349, 1191)   1
(349, 1202)   1
(349, 1628)   1
(349, 2873)   2
(349, 264)    1
(349, 692)    1
(349, 1491)   1
(349, 2107)   1
(349, 1185)   1
(349, 1072)   1
(349, 433)    3
(349, 151)    1
(349, 2870)   2
(349, 194)    1
(349, 247)    1
(349, 2740)   1
(349, 2324)   1
(349, 379)    2
(349, 1027)   3
(349, 2582)   1
(349, 2475)   2
(349, 1939)   2
(349, 1136)   2
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in your `y_train`. Check that it either has a `shape=(?, 1)` or `shape=(?)`.

Comment: shape of y_train is (350,12)

Comment: Please read the following: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html . It should help you understand the terminology better and then based on what actually you are trying to achieve read the docs of OneVSRestClassifier.